# Javascript requestAnimFrame not clearing

Tags: javascript

So I was attempting to create two circles going round the same centre in a circular orbit, however when I input the 'ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h)' (line 18) it removes the inner circle and keeps the outside one. Without the clearRect line it just keeps the circles on screen leaving a circle as it's trail (which eventually just turns into one big circle). Is there any way to prevent the inner circle from disappearing?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var dd = 3;
var dd2 = 2.26;
var angle = 0;
var angle2 = 0;
var cx = 670;
var cy = 400;
var radius = 200;
var radius2 = 300;
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
(function () {
    "use strict";
    function draw(x, y) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x - 50 / 2, y - 30 / 2, 75, 75, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    };

    var fps = 60;

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / fps);
        };
    })();


    function animate() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            requestAnimFrame(animate);
            ctx.beginPath();
            angle += Math.acos(1 - Math.pow(dd / radius, 2) / 2);
            var newX = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle),
                newY = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle);
            draw(newX, newY);
            ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            angle2 += Math.acos(1 - Math.pow(dd2 / radius2, 2) / 2);
            var newX2 = cx + radius2 * Math.cos(angle2),
                newY2 = cy + radius2 * Math.sin(angle2);
            draw(newX2, newY2);
            ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.closePath();
    }, 1000 / fps);
    }
    animate();
}());
```

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with `requestAnimationFrame()`.  In any case, read the notes about path here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect

Comment: okay thanks, probably my misunderstanding of the use of clearing the canvas =/

Comment: I think the problem is I'm clearing the canvas and then only putting in one arc `ctx.arc(x - 50 / 2, y - 30 / 2, 75, 75, 0, 2 * Math.PI);`. However I'm not sure where to put in the other circle?